# ubuntu 18.04 is slow when accessing files from a Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro

We have a NAS (installed with Ubuntu 18.04 ), when every Mac Laptop users logs it take lot of time to show the files/folder in it. Where as Windows user, i dont have any issue. Can any one help in this regards.
(Config: Macbook Pro - 2018 & 2020 with MacOS Catalina ver.10.15.7)

Comment: hello this seems more to be a mac problem and a question of the used software (samba?).

Comment: I dont think, we are able to access another NAS on Ubuntu 14.04 version; same Macbook laptop is used, its Fast in accessing files, saving etc.